# python doesn't update int in main method

Tags: python, int, program-entry-point

I'm very new to python and I'm trying to get the hang of things. It's a very easy and obvious question, but I don't know the answer. Anyways, I will first post the code:

```
import pygame,sys
import random

number = 0

def randomNumber(number):
    number = random.randint(1,10)
    print(number)
    return(number)

def main(number):

    randomNumber(number)
    print(number)

if __name__=='__main__':
    main(number)
```

If I run this program the first number that's printed out is always a number from 1 to 10, but the second number is always zero. I don't want that, I want the second number to be the same number as the first one. How can I do that? So how can I successfully update this int?

Comment: why are you passing number and not using it?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham in my actual program I use it, this is just an example

Comment: The answers below are the best approach but if you wanted to increment the number you could  `number+= randomNumber(number)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot alter a local variable in another function; `number` in `main()` is distinct from `number` in the `randomNumber()` function.

Your `randomNumber()` function does return a new value; assign it back to `number` in `main()`:

```
def main(number):
    number = randomNumber(number)
    print(number)
```

Since you are otherwise ignoring the original value of `number` as you pass it in to `randomNumber()`, you can remove the arguments altogether:

```
def randomNumber():
    number = random.randint(1,10)
    print(number)
    return number

def main():
    number = randomNumber()
    print(number)

if __name__=='__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: @PadraicCunningham: ah, so it is; the OP had it misspelled in `main()`.